# CKEditor 4 get dimensions of parent Element

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I build a small CKEditor plugin, where a button insert a span tag. The span must be the same height as the p, so i need the css line-height value or the height from the p tag. Current plugin code:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('border',{
    icons: 'border',
    init: function(editor){
        editor.addCommand('addBox',{
            exec: function(editor) {
                var box = editor.document.createElement('span');
                box.setAttribute('style', 'border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;width:40px;height:40px;vertical-align: text-top;');
                box.setAttribute('class', 'borderbox');
                editor.insertElement(box);
            }
        });
        editor.ui.addButton('empty box',{
            label: 'insert box',
            command: 'addBox',
            toolbar: 'links'
        });
    }
});
```

how can i access the parent p?

Answer (score 1):

Solution found: **editor.elementPath().elements[0]** return the first parent element.